# How to get the class where an object was originally created in

Tags: java, android

I have:

```
class OriginalClass {  
    View createMyView() {  
        TextView textView = new TextView(context);  
        return textView;  
    }  
}
```

Then:

```
class HoldingClass {  
    List<TextView> textViewsList() {  
        List<TextView> textViews = new ArrayList();  
        textViews.add(new OriginalClass().createMyView());  
        return textViews;  
    }  
}
```

Then:

```
class SomeOtherClass {  
    void aMethod() {  
        TextView receivedTextView = (new HoldingClass().textViewsList()).get(0);  
        // Retrieve original class from somewhere here  
    }  
}
```

How can I retrieve the class `receivedTextView` was "originally created in" (`OriginalClass`) from `SomeOtherClass`?

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to serve?

Comment: _Why_ would you need to do this exactly? This sounds like an X-Y problem.

Comment: I'm building an API/ Library for my app. I need to do some things in some-round-about-ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the tag when initalizing the TextView. You can retrieve the tag later.

```
textView.setTag(OriginalClass.class.getSimpleName());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can’t, except of course by making the data that you store be a pair of a `TextView` and some indication of the creating class (perhaps its `Class` object).  The language doesn’t store such information automatically, since it would be very expensive in general.

Comment: @Program-Me-Rev: Not _for_ you, no.  If you can _associate_ the class (or its name) at creation, as has been suggested by others, then of course the answer is yes.

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like that

by using `textView.setTag(getClass().getSimpleName())`

```
    class OriginalClass {  
        View createMyView() {  
            TextView textView = new TextView(context);  
            textView.setTag(getClass().getSimpleName());
            return textView;  
        }  
    }
```

then Retrieve original class name by `getTag()`

```
    class SomeOtherClass {  
        void aMethod() {  
            TextView receivedTextView = (new 
            HoldingClass().textViewsList()).get(0);  
            // Retrieve original class from somewhere here
            String originalClassName = (String) receivedTextView.getTag();  
        }  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the TextView constructor, ask the current thread for a stack trace, ask the resulting array for the 0th element and get the class

String callersClass = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[0].getClassName();